# Create WSDL for an ASP.Net Core ApiController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, service, wsdl

I am creating a service using ASP.Net Core.
The service is based on the ApiController.

```
[ApiController]
public class XmlALaCarteServiceController : ControllerBase
{
    private IXmlALaCarteConnectionProvider _connectionProvider;

    public XmlALaCarteServiceController(IXmlALaCarteConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
    {
        _connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
    }

    [Route("api/XmlALaCarteService/V1/InitializeConnection")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<InitializeResponse> InitializeConnection([FromQuery] InitializeRequest request)
    {
        InitializeResponse result = _connectionProvider.CreateConnection(request.Map()).Map();

        return result;
    }

    [Route("api/XmlALaCarteService/V1/GetDataAsXML")]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<XmlDocument> GetDataAsXML(DataRequest request)
    {
        return new XmlDocument();
    }

}
```

If I am not mistaken, other people can connect to my service and perform the actions on it.

We used to have the same service but as an asmx. This asmx came with a WSDL.
Is there a way to have the same for my new service?

Comment: WSDLs are usually used for SOAP services. But an API controller is not SOAP. If you want proper SOAP you will probably have to do quite some work to get it working with a REST-like API controller. There might be some libraries that do that for you, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore), but I have no idea how well they work. Usually, these days you are happy that you are not using the complex SOAP but rather a thin REST API.

Comment: You can use [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) to describe your REST API. There is a nuget [package](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) for asp.net core projects which can create a description document in JSON. It is very similar to soap/wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

To have your .Net Core webapi produce a WSDL/DISCO LIKE definition look at SwaggerUI by SmartBear: [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/).

NuGet Packages: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger & Swashbuckle.AspNetCore